# How do I reset the Android Wear app?

Tags: wear-os

I installed the Android Wear app on my phone to link with my Moto 360 and Android Wear emulator.  For various reasons, I would like to "reset" the Android Wear app so that it forgets about all of its connections.

I uninstalled the Android Wear app and re-downloaded it from the Google Play store, but it still remembers that it was last paired to my emulator.

How can I reset the Android Wear app to fresh-install experience?

Comment: I was about to scold you for posting this on Stack Overflow because I didn't see the word _emulator_ at first.

Comment: True :)  It's a borderline question, but it's really only something a developer would need to do. Regular users would never need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Connections to wearable devices are managed by the Google Play Services, so you should clear its data as well (warning: it will remove all other (may be) valuable data which are stored by Google Play Services).

In the device choosing screen Wear app shows all paired Bluetooth devices, so to clear this list - unpair devices in the bluetooth settings).